# Using self->ivar when accessing instance variables directly

Tags: objective-c

I have noticed that most Objective-C coders never use the `self->ivar` syntax when accessing instance variables directly. Most sample code that I see simply references the instance variable without `self->`. I think that it is rather confusing to reference an instance variable without making clear that it is an instance variable and not simply a variable of the current scope.

I feel like I want to write stuff like:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [self->someVar release];
    [self->anotherVar release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

or

```
- (void)setVar:(Foo *)newVar {
    [self->var autorelease];
    self->var = [newVar retain];
}
```

There aren't a whole lot of occasions when we ever even should access our instance variables without using an accessor for encapsulation, but sometimes we need to such as in dealloc, or in custom getters and setters.

Am I a bad person/programmer for doing this? Is there some really good reason for not writing code like this? Because it feels really good to do it this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chuck is correct in that there's no **technical** reason you shouldn't write it that way, unless you're shadowing ivars with local variables, which is is generally a bad idea. However, it's arguable that omitting `self->` is stylistically cleaner, and it certainly results in less verbose code. Personally I would find the `self->` to be distracting (especially if the code is well-designed and variables are well-named) but if it makes things more understandable for you, by all means do it. Just be aware that if you show your code to other Objective-C programmers, they're likely to have a conflicting opinion, so it's good to have a think skin. Besides, most programmers find that their perception of what makes code "feel good" changes over time and with experience, and those opinions often mellow out with age. :-)

Comment: Like I said, it's shorter. I prefer it, but I couldn't make the argument that shorter identifiers are always better, though — I'd hate to maintain code that's all x, y and z. So it's essentially a matter of where you find your happy medium. I suspect Pythonists would probably prefer the `self->` form. Of course, you shouldn't be doing direct ivar access very often in Objective-C, anyway. Maybe being unappealing is another virtue of the `self->` syntax.

Comment: Lol. "think skin". Is that skin that is sort of thin and sort of thick?

Answer (score 7):

There's no reason you shouldn't write it that way. I think people tend to write it the other way because they try to avoid shadowing their ivars anyway, so there shouldn't be any ambiguity in what variable they're talking about — and it's shorter.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: No, you are not a bad programmer because of that :) There is also no good reason for not writing code this way; most programmers are simply lazy or never really have written an exhausting method in their whole life.

Long answer: Technically when you access a variable without "self->", the compiler will first for a variable of that name in the local scope and if it cannot find one, it will repeat that search with instance variables. If it finds a hit there, it will actually generate code as if "self->..." had been written there. If there was no match for instance variables either, the compiler would try within global scope, BTW.

Most programmers only read their own code and they know pretty well what is an instance variable and what not. Once you ever had to work with code you have not written yourself, where the method is 4 screen pages long (and I have a bigg screen), you are really thankful when the programmer made it absolutely clear on every variable access: Is that variable a parameter fed to the method call, a local variable of this method, an instance variable of the object or possibly a global variable (only global to all instances of this class or possibly application global). You are thankful, because if there are just a bunch of variables with similar name and with no special naming or access pattern, however all of different type, you pretty quickly lose oversight. And relying on the fact that Xcode syntax highlighting highlights instance variables in a different way than local variables is also stupid, because no programmer is forced to edit code in Xcode to begin with and even if he does, he may have a color scheme where instance variables are the same color as local ones.

Accessing instance variables via self-> is perfectly fine, but consider also a to maybe use a prefix/suffix, which will also make obvious those are instance variables and also avoid naming conflicts with method parameters or local variables.

Answer (score 1):

Objective C automatically appends an underscore to the i-var name, so when you see "_someVar" it is implicitly of class scope. The underscore is enough of a visual marker to make its scope clear without adding self->.

Comment: I agree with you, that if you see `_someVar` released in `dealloc` or set in a custom setter, you can be reasonably confident that it's an ivar. But if I saw `someVar` in those contexts, I'd probably still assume it was an ivar, just one that was manually defined or manually synthesized (with `@synthesize`). Bottom line, it's a tad strong to say that a leading `_` means that it is "implicitly" an ivar. The underscore is neither necessary nor sufficient condition. But you're right that best practice is to use properties, let ivars be synthesized for you, and they'll have the leading underscore.